# Conditional for loop in python

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have two DataFrames: `dfSide0` and `dfSide1` that have the same columns but a different number of rows. `dfSide0` has 17096 rows and `dfSide1` has 4961 rows. What I want to do is get the minimum of all possible subtractions between the values of `dfSide0['distoperator']`
and `dfSide1['distoperator']` but only when the condition `dfSide0['camera_row'] == dfSide1['camera_row']` is True.

So I do the following:

```
temp = []
for i in dfSide0['distoperator']:
    if dfSide0['camera_row'] == dfSide1['camera_row']:
        c = min(abs(i - dfSide1['distoperator']))
        temp.append(c)
```

and I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-225-625fcefe40b7> in <module>()
      1 temp = []
      2 for i in dfSide0['distoperator']:
----> 3     if dfSide0['camera_row'] == dfSide1['camera_row']:
      4         c = min(abs(i - dfSide1['distoperator']))
      5         temp.append(c)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
   1188 
   1189         elif isinstance(other, ABCSeries) and not self._indexed_same(other):
-> 1190             raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled "
   1191                              "Series objects")
   1192 

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Otherwise the downvotes will just roll in...

Comment: Your indentation in your example code is off and for a comparison you use `==` instead of `=`. Besides that, it is difficult to help without knowing what your data looks like.

Comment: If you have a different number of rows, then how can `dfSide0['columnx'] == dfSide1['columnx']`? You don't compare row-by-row here, but the entire series...

Comment: Yes, the dataframes have a different number of rows. So how do you suggest that I implement this condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer:

```
temp = []
k = -1
for i in dfSide0['distoperator']:
    k = k+1
    j = dfSide0.index[k]
    c = min(abs(i - dfSide1['distoperator'][dfSide1['camera_row'] == dfSide0['camera_row'][j]]))
    temp.append(c)
```

It seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick respone. 
To make things more clear:
dfSide0 and dfSide1 both have two columns: 'distance' which is a float and 'camera_row' which is a string with the values 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' and 'f'
dfSide0 has 17096 rows and dfSide1 has 4961 rows. 
I need to subtract all the values in column 'distance' between the two dataframes and find the minimum, but only when the value in column 'camera_row' is the same. The exact code so far is the following:

```
temp = []
for i in dfSide0['distance']:
    c = min(abs(i - dfSide1['distance']))
    temp.append(c)
```

and it works, but I haven't found a way to accually do this for loop only when

`dfSide0['camera_row'] == dfSide1['camera_row']`

Comment: == you need to use == and not = for comparisons. Just add if dfSide0['camera_row'] == dfSide1['camera_row']: on the line before the for loop and indent appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

if I do this:

```
temp = []
for i in dfSide0['distoperator']:
    if dfSide0['camera_row'] == dfSide1['camera_row']:
        c = min(abs(i - dfSide1['distoperator']))
        temp.append(c)
```

I get the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-222-625fcefe40b7> in <module>()
      1 temp = []
      2 for i in dfSide0['distoperator']:
----> 3     if dfSide0['camera_row'] == dfSide1['camera_row']:
      4         c = min(abs(i - dfSide1['distoperator']))
      5         temp.append(c)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
   1188 
   1189         elif isinstance(other, ABCSeries) and not self._indexed_same(other):
-> 1190             raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled "
   1191                              "Series objects")
   1192 

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

without the if statement it runs fine.